# Domain Events - Inheritance or use of enums

Tags: event-handling, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, domain-events

So guess that I have this kind of domain events:

```
class BookChangedName...
class BookType1ChangedName extends BookChangedName...
class BookType2ChangedName extends BookChangedName...
```

Is that better or:

```
class BookChangedName{
    enum bookType = BOOK_TYPE_1;
}
```

Since they say use inheritance only if there is a different behavior between classes, I assume here I would go with enum sample (case #2) - since Domain Events are just plain simple DTOs.

But again, in my domain this different types of events have different meaning (different processing paths). So in case I use example #1 i would end up with a lot of:

```
if(event instanceof BookType1ChangedName){
   //do smth in domain
}
else if(event instanceof BookType2ChangedName){
   //do smth in domain
}
```

and also I could not be as explicit as:

```
when(BookType1ChangedName event){...
```

I would have to do some kind of pre-processing like:

```
@EventHandler(matcher_pattern = event->event.bookType==BOOK_TYPE_1)
when(BookChangedNameevent){...
```

Comment: If your booktypes are different aggregates, may be with single parent if you use inheritance, you can use the same event and have handlers in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Do your domain experts use the phrase "BookType1"? You said that there are different logic paths for each book type - I'd suggest interrogate the rational for that, and perhaps there is a more domain-oriented name for each event?  Try and listen for the language used by the domain experts to describe the two situations.

If you can find more descriptive language, I would go with separate events based on inheritence.  With some domain event mechanisms, you can subscribe to handle either the abstract super class or either of the specialisations, which may be helpful if you want that flexibility.

On the other hand, if it really is just booktype1 and booktype2 and in the future maybe booktype3 and booktype4, I'd consider either an enum or even just an integer and consider implementing the different logic paths in different *strategies* and have your domain event handler use a *factory* to return the appropriate strategy for the given book type, then delegate to the strategy to execute the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Event names are an important part in DDD (in fact any "name"is important) so I suggest to use different event names for different events as those names carry a lot of information.  Also,  if you use a type code (with `enum`) you increase the `CRAP` index because of the additional `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a single BookChangedName event and have a BookType property for that event. The handler/subscriber of the event should take care of the logic.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind that statement?

Comment: They are similar events BookChangedName, BookType1ChangedName, BookType2ChangedName , etc. Instead of creating different event classes for each book type, just let the handler of the event implement how each book type gets processed. The handler can use a strategy pattern so it does not have to deal with if/else statements.